# Consul.IO - How to watch key/value data and announce to ASP.NET Web application to know these changes

Tags: asp.net, consul

Currently, I use Consul for storing App Settings and Configurations for ASP.NET Web application. But I got performance issue when every request need to query from Consul service. 
I see Consul have watch feature in server but I did not know how to use it in Windows and how to announce Web Application know when key/value data change

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, watches allow you to invoke some handlers, which must be some executables. So you have to provide some API in your web-app to allow  remotely call to reload configuration, for example, some kind of REST web service or something else, what can be called from outside.

Next you have to create some executable script on your agent's host and provide a logic to call this remote API of your web-app.

And finally you have to register a new watch, providing your script file as an executable.

Comment: I think about it before, but will reloading configuration have any problems? Like performance bla bla

Comment: I depends on what and how you update and how often too. If your configuration changes once a year, don't think it would cause any problem, but if it changes every second...